# Change content and send it back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the content inside a custom directive - change it and send it back (I have seen some questions on SO but just for replace). I have:

HTML

```
<glossary categoryID="199">Hello and welcome to my site</glossary>
```

JS

```
.directive('glossary', [ function () {

    return {
        // I need to get the current content here first I think before setting template? Also the attributes on the custom dir?

        template: "<strong>Welcome</strong>",
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            transclude(function (clone) {
                element.replace(clone);
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Please provide the expected rendered HTML to give a better idea of what you're trying to do

Comment: <glossary categoryID="199">Hello and <strong>Welcome</strong> to my site</glossary>

Comment: I would not suggest using transclusion for this. Transclusion means "I'll put your stuff in my stuff" where as your goal is "I want to add to your stuff"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest using transclusion for this.

Transclusion means: "I'll put your stuff in my stuff"

Where as your goal is: "I want to add to your stuff"

You can leave your markup alone and change your directive to this:

```
.directive('glossary', [
  function() {
    var replaceTemplate = '<strong>Welcome</strong>';
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        element.html(element.html().replace('welcome', replaceTemplate))
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Working **[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/rEPpwLSd86BvxLJchoAG?p=preview)**